# Cordova platform add android fails

Tags: android, cordova

```
~/PhoneGap/app-hello-world$ cordova platform add android
[Error: An error occured during creation of android sub-project.  
/home/jj/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.0.0/bin/create: line 104: ant: command not
found
An unexpected error occurred: ant jar > /dev/null exited with 127
Deleting project...
]
```

After creating a cordova project i tried to add android to the platform but fails like this.
I do have sdk tools and platform-tools exposed in my PATH, so if I type android on terminal it opens sdk manager.

For more information, I installed cordova through sudo npm install -g cordova, and got an warning message saying:

```
/usr/local/bin/cordova -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/couch-login
requires request@'~2.9.202' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 2.21.0
```

Any type of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem. Solved by installing ant.

Comment: need to tell how you fixed it using ant

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the following:

1. Upgrade JAVA / Reinstall JAVA / Make sure ant is there
2. Follow the [Cordove Android Platform Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) to make sure you have the SDK correctly installed on your machine

Comment: I was using Cordova CLI. I tried npm install request but didn't fix the problem. I dont quite understand your last point. I have an android sdk and exported the tools and platform-tools through changing the ~/.bashrc file. Isn't this enough? What is project.properties file and what do you mean by ant can't be fouond within the SDK; should I include it manually in SDK?

Comment: Ahhh, yes. Import the relevant JAR library for "ant". This might be your problem... or not... that's after you created the android project & have loaded it into Eclipse

Comment: Ant is a pretty core JAVA tool though. Perhaps try upgrading your java, or installing ant.. http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html

Comment: Yeah, It was ant problem. Now I get another error but seems like it's caused by wrong javac path